# Me podrían explicar los valores que van en smtp_user y $this->email->from en la libreria email de codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

estoy confundido ya que en algunos ejemplos que e visto from y smtp_user tienen los mismos valores y en otros son diferentes y no entiendo porque porfa alguien que me ilumine ya que estoy empezando en esto y ya e leído en varios foros pero todos dicen lo mismo y no logro entender

```
             $config = Array(
              'protocol' => 'smtp',
              'smtp_host' => 'host',
              'smtp_port' => '26',
              'smtp_user' => 'info@29ana.website',
              'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxx',
              'mailtype' => 'html',
              'charset' => 'utf-8',
              'wordwrap' => TRUE,
               'crlf' => "\r\n",
              'newline' => "\r\n"
            );
            
            $this->load->library('email', $config);
            $this->email->clear(TRUE);
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->from('info@manager.com', 'CRM');
            $this->email->to('marca@gmail.com');
            $this->email->subject('oli');
            $this->email->message('holi');
            if ($this->email->send()) {
                //si envia
                echo 'Email send.';
                //echo $contacemail;
                //$this->Mevent->update_status($email[$j]->csent_id);

            } else {
                // si no envia lanza el posible error
                show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
            }
```

'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

- El usuario que indicas en `smtp_user` es el que se usa **para conectarse al servidor** (vía SMTP) para enviar el correo.
- El usuario que indicas en `$this->email->from()` es el que aparece como remitente del email (en el programa cliente de quien lo recibe) y al que se le podrá responder (a menos que no hayas indicado otra dirección de respuesta).

---

Dentro de `$config`, como su nombre lo indica, lo que haces es configurar tu correo.

Como quizá ya sabrás, `SMTP` (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol o Protocolo para Transferencia Simple de Correo) es un protocolo de comunicación que permite el envío de correos electrónicos en internet. Este protocolo se asocia normalmente con otros como `POP3` o `IMAP`, siendo `SMTP` utilizado para el **correo de salida** y `POP3` o `IMAP` utilizado para el correo entrante.

Entonces, cuando configuras el valor `'smtp_user' => 'info@29ana.website',` lo que estás indicando es: *en el contexto donde use esta configuración, cuando se vaya a mandar un correo, debes autentificarte **con este usuario**, con esta contraseña: `'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxx',`, debes conectarte en este puerto: `'smtp_port' => '26',`*  etc. En palabras breves, configuras todo lo que respecta **a la conexión** para el envío de correos electrónicos.

Por otra parte, en `$this->email->from()` lo que haces es indicar quién es el remitente de ese correo, independientemente de la forma en que se haya hecho la conexión para fines de envío.

En teoría, tú podrías conectarte con un usuario a nivel SMTP y poner en `email->from()` otro usuario, aunque esto podría ser problemático, cada vez los servidores de email son más exigentes y esta situación podría hacer que tus mensajes sean marcados como SPAM.

En un cliente de correos cualquiera como Outlook, Mail, Firebird, etc. uno puede conectarse a un servidor SMTP de una cuenta de correos (`cuenta.uno@gmail.com` por ejemplo) y poner en el `From` otra dirección (`cuenta.dos@icloud.com` por ejemplo). Pero en la configuración SMTP debes poner tus credenciales de `cuenta.uno@gmail.com`. Cuando se envíe un mensaje, el cliente se conectará a los servidores de GMail y enviará el correo desde esos servidores. Pero quien los reciba verá (de cara a la galería) que ese mensaje se está enviando desde una cuenta de iCloud. Digo de cara a la galería, porque si examinas el **código fuente** de ese mensaje, verás que para la autentificación y demás se usaron los servidores de Gmail. Realmente el mensaje se envió desde `GMail`, pero el receptor verá tu dirección de `iCloud`.

En tu caso ocurre algo parecido. Aunque como ya dije, deberías tener cuidado. Los servidores de correo son más exigentes con las cuentas de email personalizadas, sobre todo cuando se envían correos electrónicos a listas de distribución y demás.

En [este artículo](https://www.codexworld.com/codeigniter-send-email-gmail-smtp-server/) hay dos ejemplos. En el primero se indica una configuración donde la conexión SMTP se haría al propio servidor del remitente (`example.com`), en la segunda, la conexión se haría al servidor SMTP de Google, y se usaría un remitente de `example.com`.

Pero como ya dije, hay que tener cuidado con esto y tratar de ser lo más transparentes posible en tu configuración. En el enlace dan una sugerencia si experimentas que al hacer esto tus correos son marcados como SPAM:

> Si nota que los correos electrónicos se envían a la carpeta de correo
> no deseado, use Encrypt Class en CodeIgniter para resolver este
> problema en Gmail. Debe cargar la biblioteca CodeIgniter Encrypt antes
> de enviar el correo electrónico. Encriptará su correo electrónico y
> ayudará a evitar el problema del spam en Gmail.
>
> ```
> $this->load->library ('encriptar');
> ```

Si tu dominio está suscrito a una cuenta de WorkSpace, otra cosa sería. Podrías usar sin miedo a SPAM los servidores de Google para mandar tus correos desde tu cuenta de dominio personal.

Por ilustrar lo que he dicho antes, veamos el código fuente de un email cualquiera, encontrado en mi bandeja de SPAM:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese mensaje burló todos los filtros SPF (recuadros verdes), pero se estrelló ante un filtro DMARC (recuadro rojo). Porque allí se encontró un encabezado con otro nombre de dominio distinto al que hasta el momento parecía ser el servidor remitente (el que había pasado todos los filtros SPF). Ese criterio, y muchos otros que no se ven reflejados aquí, hicieron que mi cliente de correo determinase, de forma acertada, que era un SPAM.

Es muy probable, por ejemplo, que el dominio `cdkeygame.com`, aunque aparezca como un *permitted sender*, haya sido incluido en una lista negra, al detectar varios casos en los que se usa su servidor SMTP para mandar mensajes, pero indicando como remitentes usuarios de otros dominios o poniendo encabezados relativos a otros dominios.

Creo que la imagen es un ejemplo claro de la diferencia entre el usuario SMTP que se usa para conectarse al servidor y enviar el mensaje, y el remitente, de cara a la galería.

Comment: gracias por responder estimado, ya me quedo clarísimo